# How to backup and restore your local Minecraft files?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a general problem with my Windows 8 PC that requires I wipe and reinstall Windows. What is the correct procedure for backing up my minecraft saves and mods and then restoring them on a clean Windows 8 again?

Comment: copy your .minecraft folder to external storage device and put it back into the same place....

Answer (score 4):

You need to copy your full .minecraft folder. The folder contains every game files with your saves and mods.

The easiest way to reach this folder is by opening the launch windows `Win + R` on your keyboard and entering `%appdata%`. From there, find the `.minecraft` folder and copy it where you want to make your backup (in a USB key since you are wiping your computer.

Comment: And if you are just in the same mod, it will be enough to copy just the files in the "saves" folder `C:\Users\MyAdmin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy your .minecraft folder to a detachable storage device such as a USB drive, or SkyDrive, and then copy it back when your reinstallation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to backup up your world there are plenty of utilities that can achieve this. the one i use is [Server Tools mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1289612-1-6-4-1-7-2-forge-server-tools)

although it appears to be a server tool it works perfectly for single player and allows for timed backups or you can use a command to generate it.