# How do I transfer minecraft worlds to sandisk flash drive?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've managed to download Minecraft onto my SandDisk USB thumbdrive.
But how do I copy all my worlds to it?

Comment: VTR: This is asking how to transfer world files, not the entire game itself.

Comment: True, but there's other duplicates: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14702/where-are-my-minecraft-saves-located and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163377/how-to-backup-and-restore-your-local-minecraft-files

Answer (score 2):

Worlds are saved in the computer hard drive.

If you open explorer and go to `%appdata%`, you will see `.minecraft`.

[image: %appdata%]

The subfolder **saves** contains the folders with the worlds you want.

[image: subfolder saves]

**Tip**: `%appdata%` is the same as `C:\Users\George\AppData\Roaming`, where you replace "George" with your name.

Comment: On Linux the path is `~/.minecraft` and on Mac it's `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft`. The approach is the same.