# How to save a world / make a backup in Minecraft on Windows in Single Player or local Multiplayer mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows

Sharing this although it is surely well-told on:

- [How to Create a Back Up of Your World on Minecraft](https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Back-Up-of-Your-World-on-Minecraft),
- [How to Backup, Restore, and Sync Your Minecraft Saves on All Your PCs](https://www.howtogeek.com/60264/how-to-backup-restore-and-sync-your-minecraft-saves-on-all-your-pcs/).

How to save a world / make a backup in Minecraft on Windows in Single Player or local Multiplayer mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just click on `Edit` in the main menu after having marked your world. Choose the button for the backup. Then choose the button to open the backup folder. This folder is in

`C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves`.

For example, you can save that to a stick and paste it in the same folder of another installation to restore that world from the Minecraft menu.

This folder has the backup also in local multiplayer mode, and any linked computer saves it there. Thus, you can get the saved world from any member of the game, you do not need to ask the local server admin for this.

If you just want to save the world and open it again somewhere else, or after new installation, loading from `saves` folder is enough.

##### Backing up a mod

Saving only the `saves` folder is not enough if you also have a [mod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft_modding) to save: you should then save the whole `.minecraft` folder, see [How to backup and restore your local Minecraft files?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/175022/307307).